# Pop up when button is click - across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, alert

I'm trying to get it so when a link is pressed a pop up appears, however I'm wanting it to appear not only on the page it was clicked but on every page that is currently opened on any computer.

The idea is so when the  button or link is clicked everyone who is on the site is notified of that action... If anyone knows how this could be achieved that would be great Thanks !

Comment: Firebase Database issues a trigger eveytime something is changed, listen to it and trigger the popup. This of course highly depends on you're server.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your server set up ? Also what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you'll need is an event triggered server-side (something along the lines of what @Kriggs said above) and a way to push this notification to each connected client. See [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for something like this.
This would require that your server supports WebSockets, of course.

Either that, or something like `setInterval` running on the client's browsers, where every x amount of time, it makes an AJAX call to the server. If a flag is set on the server, then return and show this popup/notification to each client.